# how to get the liquidity pool token amount by web3j with the contract hash

Tags: liquidity-provider

i want to get the token amount in the liquidity pool, is there any api to do it by web3j? thx very much. it is the amount in this picture [image: liquidity pool token amount]

Comment: Most pools has their own API, what pool is this? like from what company?

Comment: you mean that we need to use the every pool's own api to get the token amount? i wonder why etherscan can do that like the result in the picture, does it use all the pools api?